# Which passes can I access in Apple Wallet

Tags: ios, swift, passkit

I am new to iOS development and want to work on a small project using the PassKit library.

After a lot of searching (Apple docs, stackoverflow) I just can't seem to get a clear understanding of possible answers to my question:

"Is it possible to access passes that I did not create?"

Now, I'm not talking about payment related passes like bank cards etc. I simply want an overview of things like event tickets, transportation passes and so on.

Is there any way to achieve this? (with the users consent of course)

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is "No, Your app cannot access passes that it did not create"; this would be a potential privacy violation.

The more detailed answer is that your app *can access passes it did not create* as long as the pass type identifiers are specified in the `com.apple.developer.pass-type-identifiers` entitlement for your app.  The purpose of this entitlement is to allow one app to access passes created by another app from the same developer.

This entitlement can also allow an app to access passes that were added to the wallet through some other method; For example, an airline app could access a pass that was added to the wallet through checking in on the airline's web site.

The answer to the question in your title is "You can access passes that you created".

There is no request that an app can make that will result in a request to the user to allow general pass access.

Comment: Thanks so much @Paulw11! Nothing to be done about it then. Gotta move on to a different idea. Have a great day!